# Android 4.4 Step Detector and Counter

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Is there any documentation around Android 4.4 KitKat's (well specifically Nexus 5 for now) step detector and counter APIs? I tried to search a lot but did not find anything.

I am planning to try my hands on these new concepts and want to use the API but there's nothing around it on the Internet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found an example for you, hope it helps in someway, the sensor explanation on the API page is pretty straight forward too..

API Page:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UserInput

Blog Post: http://theelfismike.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/android-4-4-kitkat-step-detector-code/
Github Project referenced in the blog: https://github.com/theelfismike/android-step-counter

Comment: I have been looking into this too. One thing i am still unclear on is whether its a piece of hardware or rather an algorithm applied to the accelerometer?  Some links refer to it as only being available in Nexus 5 but the documentation makes it sound like it would be available to any device running kitkat that has an accelerometer

Comment: It's a piece of hardware. The API is there on all KitKat devices, but you'll need to check if the device in question actually has a stepcount sensor.

Comment: I found out the accuracy to be very questionable; if you simply shake the phone, it registers it as a step. The Google sample app is not better than this simple app at the fact that it suffers from the same accuracy issues.

Answer (score 3):

**Official example**

In Android SDK 23 under `samples/android-23/sensors/BatchStepSensor`, run with:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew installDebug
```

Then turn on the app, enable one of the step sensors, and walk around with your phone to see the counter increment.

Source at: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BatchStepSensor