# Access runtastic app data

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on an application which shows steps count. I want to access step counts from runtastic app. how can I access that data?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?Can you share some of your codes?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (probably).
Android applications' security bases on isolation of data. So one app can't access some other app's data, unless it's not directly shared using ContentProvider component. As far as I see - there is no Runtastic API that allows to count such data.

However, good news are: there is an Android API that allows you to count user's steps. You can start with this [Android 4.4 Step Detector and Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367402/android-4-4-step-detector-and-counter) question.

Comment: is it possible to access data from Samsung's  S health app as they provide SDK for developers also it is an in-built app.